# Why is StringVar().set(LocalScript) receiving a function id instead of a return value

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I'm running Python 3.4 with Tkinter.  I'm trying to get a `StringVar()` in a label to update constantly from a script and refresh the screen with new data (I'm going to start with the time).  But first, I'm just trying to get the label to display the output of a function:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

def localScript():
    return str(datetime.now().time())
```

I'm assigning my `StringVar()` to that functions return type as such:

```
textVar1 = StringVar()
textVar1.set(str(localScript))
```

And this is my output: `<function localScript at 0x02325f60>`

I'm new to Python so I don't quite understand it's version of scope.  `localScript` is defined globally, whereas the assignment is executed inside a class (in the same `.py` file of course).  Maybe it's a problem of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, you need to place `(...)` after a function name in order to call it:

```
textVar1.set(localScript())
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> def func():
...     return 'hi'
...
>>> func  # Below is a string representation of the function object itself
<function func at 0x01B4EBB0>
>>> func()  # The () calls func.  Below is the return value of the function
'hi'
>>>
```

Here is a [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) on defining/calling functions in Python.

Comment: So that was just returnign the `__repr__` function then.  I'm an idiot